# started with verilog and trying to understand what is happening in this piece of code of module instantiation

Tags: verilog, instantiation

```
clock #(.N(N))  //-- N parameter
Pres1(
.CLK(clk),
.O_SPI_CLK(clk_out) );
```

what i don't understand is #(.N(N) and use of pres1();

Comment: You are probably looking at an extremely old version of the Verilog standard. The `#(.N(N))` syntax was added in 2001. The current version is [IEEE 1800-2017](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) and this is explained in section *23.10.2 Module instance parameter value assignment*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog uses modules to define a group of devices in a hierarchical manner. Module instances define a hardware device. Every module instance has a name.

```
   moddedf modinst(params);
```

where moddef is the namd of the module definition (similar to a function of procedure in a generic programming languate).  'modinst' is the name of the instance of the module (not commonly found in generic programming languages). Instances are used to express hierarchy of hardware designs.

so, in your case

```
clock Pres1(...);
```

module 'clock' is instatntiated with instance name 'Pres1'.

Instance parameters (defined within  a module definition) represent connections between hardware devices (module instance).

```
clock Pres1(.CLK(clk),.O_SPI_CLK(clk_out) );
```

in the above, port `CLK` of module 'clock' is connected to a wire 'clk' and  port `O_SPI_CLK` is connected tot he wire `clk_out`. Types of the ports (net, variabel) are supposed to be defined within the module definition, and type of the signals connected to it in the module which instantiates the module 'clock' (a parent module).

Apparently, module 'clock' also uses parameter `N`. Parameter is similar to a constant in a generic language. Parameter `N` is also defined in the parent module.

```
clock#(.N(N1)) Pres1(.CLK(clk),.O_SPI_CLK(clk_out) );
```

In the above a value of the parameter(constant) `N1` defined in the parent module is assigned to the parameter `N` int the module 'clock'. I intentionally changed N to N1 to make it a bit more clear. There is no need to change it otherwise.

so,

```
clock#(.N(N)) Pres1(.CLK(clk),.O_SPI_CLK(clk_out) );
```

instantiates module `clock` as an instance `Pres1`, connects its `CLK` and `O_SPI_CLK` ports to signals `clk` and `clk_out` and passes parameter `N` to the parameter `N` of the module.

Answer (score 0):

That means that there is a module called `clock` somewhere and you want to take make an instance of it in your code, think of it like `int x` that means that the variable x is an instance of type int and x is the name of that variable, same here `pres1` is an instance of type `clock`, the module `clock` has a parameter inside of it called `N` that means that every instance can call the module `clock` but with every instance can have a different value of `N`, the module named `clock` has 2 ports one named `CLK` and the other is named `O_SPI_CLK` so in your instance you have to connect them and in your case you connected them with 2 wires(or reg) one named `clk` which is conneceted to the port `CLK` and `clk_out` which is connected to the port `O_SPI_CLK`